# regex issue with ab*a

Tags: php, regex

a* means zero or more of a.

In the string 'abbabba'  we have two occurrence of abba. (abba)bba and abb(abba).
preg_match_all matches only first occurrence.

Am i missing any basic of regex fundamental?

```
$string = 'abbabba';

preg_match_all("/ab*a/", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => abba ) )
```

Comment: You might just want to look ahead for the `a` at the end and add it to your matches later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Searches subject for all matches to the regular expression given in pattern and puts them in matches in the order specified by flags.
>
> After the first match is found, the subsequent searches are continued on from end of the last match.

[Source](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all)

Answer (score 3):

Because `ab*a` consumes text. It means the parser matches the first occurrence `abba` and starts again from `bba`, not matching with your pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) together with a capturing group:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=(ab*a))/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[1];
```

Comment: Cool. At first glance I would have guessed it impossible. Learn something new every day. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

The `*` indicates a greedy search.  When the engine sees `b*` it will match all the way to the end of the string and move backwards until it gets to a `b`, then it will check if the matched string to that point matches your pattern.

First it looks to match the `a`, which it does right off the bat.  Then it sees `b*` so it matches the string all the way up until the last occurrence of `b` in the string after the first a (because the `*` indicates the b should match 'greedily'), essentially matching `abb` at this point.  It then sees it needs to match another `a` to make a successful match, so it grabs the next character, which is an `a`, and then it's done, leaving `bba` remaining, which won't match your pattern.  Hope this helps.

If you do what Omega said you will achieve epic victory.

Comment: No, `b*` can only match `b`, so it will stop matching as soon as it runs out of `b`s--in this case, at the next `a`.  What you say would be true if the OP had used `.*` instead of `b*`. but backtracking is not an issue in this case.

Answer (score 2):

To find number of occurrences go with:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=ab*a)/', $input, $result); 
print(count($result[0]));
```

To find matches, use:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=(ab*a))/', $input, $result); 
print_r($result[1]);
```